# image preprocessing is not working in vgg16

Tags: python-3.x, keras, vgg-net, imagenet

I am learning image classification using transfer learning(vgg16) and I am using inbuilt fashion mnist dataset of keras.

```py
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

to preprocess the data for vgg16, I used the below commands by importing preprocess_input from keras.applications.vgg16

```py
X_train = preprocess_input(x_train)
X_test = preprocess_input(x_test)

train_features = vgg16.predict(np.array(X_train), batch_size=256, verbose=1)
test_features = vgg16.predict(np.array(X_test), batch_size=256, verbose=1)
```

but I am getting the below error

```py
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)
```

I am using keras2.2.4, pip 19.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Fashion mnist dataset has grayscale images it means it has only single channel in depth and [VGG16](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) is trained with RGB images with 3 channels in depth. According to your error you can not use VGG16 with single channel input. To use VGG16 for fashion mnist dataset you have to read images as three channel. You can further process your `X_train` and `X_test` as follows using [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```
import numpy as np
X_train = np.stack((X_train,)*3, axis=-1)
X_test = np.stack((X_test,)*3, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

VGG accepts a minimum of 32 and max of 224, which can be seen [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/vgg19.py#L96), to reshape this, we can do

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1) # converting it to (,28x28x1)
x_train = np.pad(x_train, ((0,0),(2,2),(2,2),(0,0)), 'constant',constant_values=(0, 0)) # converting it to min (,32x32x1)
x_train = np.stack((x_train,)*3, axis=-1) # (,32,32,1,3)
x_train = x_train[:,:,:,0,:] # (,32,32,1)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
```

This can be used easily for .fit(), .evaluate() and .predict() in keras without the need to convert it into tensor data and write generators.